# howto write a good Immediate execution function?

Tags: javascript

1.often in my code

```
(function(){})();
```

2.often read

```
(function(){}.call(this));
```

there are works well. which one is better? why?

Comment: This depends just on your usecase. If the first is fine for you, use the first.

Comment: It differs in what `this` is inside the function. There's no "better", it depends on what you want.

Comment: why  `this`  used in second? Does it works?

Comment: No need for parens though. You can convert a function definition into function expression and invoke it immediately by a preceding `void` like `void function(v){console.log(v)}(100);`

Comment: Well, yes, "it works". You may want to learn what `call` does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: I know what call does! but I can't understand `this` here.

Comment: call(this) passes context to the function. In the function body you will be able to access fields of this. Otherwize this will be null inside function body.

Comment: Look at @deceze link, it explains what I've said in examples.

Comment: @Redu,@deceze Thanks for ur answer, but urs answer in my knowledge! I just want to know why passes `this` in a immediate function? Because it makes no sense

Comment: why not `(function(){}.call());` instead of `(function(){}.call(this));`

Comment: (function(){console.log(this.message);})(); will fail because "this" is undefined inside function body. In order to resolve this issue you need to specify which object is "this" (it should contain message field in my case) for your function.

Comment: @Access Denied ,Thanks for your answer, But  immediate function just contain one function in my case

Comment: We don't know why the author of this code snippet specifically decided to use `.call(this)`. Fact is: without `.call(this)` the value of `this` inside the function will be undefined/global, while with `.call(this)` it is whatever `this` is here. Period. No more, no less.

Comment: @Carson `.call(this)` makes sense depending on when the IIFE is invoked. Check the 3rd and 4th snippets in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally an IIFE is always bound to the global context. In your second snippet its bound to the context supplied by the first argument of call. Such as without call

```js
var a = 20,
  obj = {a:10};

(function(){console.log(this.a)})()
```

But you can change the context with call

```js
var a = 20,
  obj = {a:10};


(function(){console.log(this.a)}.call(obj))
```

You might think `.call(this)` would always refer to the global object but it may not be the case depending on exactly at what time the IIFE is invoked. Let's extend our example in which the IIFEs are invoked only when  `o.b()` is called.

Wiithout `.call(this)`

```js
var a = 20,
  obj = {a:10,
         b: function(){
              return (function(){console.log(this.a)})()
            }
        };

obj.b();
```

and with `.call(this)`

```js
var a = 20,
  obj = {a:10,
         b: function(){
              return (function(){console.log(this.a)}.call(this))
            }
        };

obj.b();
```

Comment: but in my case IIFE is always bound to the global context.